# How to Display Most View Post in the template file?

Tags: posts, functions, templates, views, popular-posts

I need to create most viewed post column in the template file, but based on post view count?

**Function File**

```
function wpb_get_post_views($postID){
$count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
}
return $count.' Views';
}
```

**Template File**

```
<?php 
$popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
 while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
 the_title();
 endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Maybe you can add more information or some use cases.

Comment: brother i need to display most viewed post in the template file without any plugin?

Comment: Where is `wpb_post_views_count` coming from? Note that tracking view counts via post meta is extremely unreliable, suffers from race conditions leading to undercounting, and is fundamentally incompatible with fullpage caching and CDNs

Answer (score 0):

The function getPostViews() is retrieving the total number of views for each post while setPostViews() increases the post views counter each time post is viewed.
You need to call setPostViews() somewhere in your single.php and then use below code to retrieve posts on basis of posts view count.

```
$args = Array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => '5',
  'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
$popular = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php while($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post();  ?>

    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> <?php the_title(); ?> <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: i need try it but code didn't working properly it is showing empty column?

Comment: check db to see if your setpostview function is working or not

Comment: setpostview function is working and showing count numbers?

Comment: i updated my answer, use meta_value_num instead of meta_value. This should work

Comment: it is showing only one post and didn't change based on `meta_value_num`?

Comment: how many posts do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68857/discussion-between-piyush-rawat-and-farhan-dharsi).